# How to keep Qt binary packages between Windows reinstall

Tags: qt, qt-creator

How can i keep the installed binary packages of multiple Qt versions between windows reinstallation. I would like to be able to update these packages with maintenance tool.

Comment: I don't know about installed prebuilt binaries, but if you do your own qt builds, those work just fine in between windows re-installations, as long you maintain the path, which is a requirement due to some rather silly hardcoded paths which are all over the framework.

Comment: I never build them. I also asked on reddit how to build, because i needed the MSVC 2017 32-bit which is not between prebuilt packages, but no luck so far. Only a advice that 2015 is binary compatible with 2017.